# Mimic the Input type range of a website

Tags: jquery, css, forms, input

I'm trying to reproduced exactly the following page:http://mailchimp.com/pricing/

```
What I need:
- Input type range from 0 to 1Million
- Be able to let the user to only select the following values: 2000,10000,15000,25000,50000,75000,100000,200000,500000,750000,1000000
- Custom the css input as this page: http://mailchimp.com/pricing/
- Select automatically one of the 3 different offer via the input. Starting -> 0 - 2000 // Growing -> 2000 - 50000 // Pro->50000 - max
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any plugin to be able to select specific value with an input "range"...

If anyone know a plugin or have a working solution, I will be pleased =)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed it by using the [nouislider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) plugin and the feature "Using the slider with huge numbers".
Works like a charm =)